# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Good day.
I wanted to make a mute in which all roles will be removed from the member, and after the end of the mute, all roles will return back. The current roles should be written to the database (mongodb) so that the bot then knows which roles to return. But I got an error and I don't understand how to solve it. Hope for help.

```py
@commands.command()
async def hardmute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, mute_time : Optional[int] = None, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    mute = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=1234567809876543)
    roles = ", ".join([str(r.id) for r in member.roles if r != ctx.guild.default_role])
    if reason is None:
        await ctx.send('Need reason')
    else:
        await member.add_roles(mute)
        await member.remove_roles(*roles)
        await member.send(f"You was hardmuted in {guild.name} by {ctx.author}. {reason})")
        await ctx.channel.send(f'{member.mention} was hardmuted by {ctx.author.mention}. {reason})')

        post = {"_id": member.id, "name": member.display_name+'#'+member.discriminator, "roles": roles, "reason": reason, "time": mute_time}
        muted_members.insert_one(post)
        
        for user_id in muted_members:
            info = muted_members[user_id]
        if(mute_time != 0):
            await asyncio.sleep(mute_time)
            await member.add_roles(*info["roles"])
            await member.remove_roles(mute)
            await ctx.channel.send(f'{member.mention} now you can speak')
            muted_members.delete_one(post)
```

```
Ignoring exception in command hardmute:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\12345\python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\12345\bot\osnova\moderation copy.py", line 425, in hardmute
    await member.remove_roles(*roles)
  File "D:\12345\python\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 822, in remove_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\12345\python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "D:\12345\python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "D:\12345\python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
roles = ", ".join([str(r.id) for r in member.roles if r != ctx.guild.default_role])
...
await member.remove_roles(*roles)
```

`roles` is a string, which is the wrong argument type for `remove_roles()`.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=remove_roles#discord.Member.remove_roles

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
roles = ", ".join([str(r.id) for r in member.roles if r != ctx.guild.default_role])
```

With

```
roles = [r for r in member.roles if r != ctx.guild.default_role]
```